# Rome FCO Transfer

Tags: transit, fco

I'm travelling using a booked Etihad ticket from London to Abu Dhabi with transfer in Rome. I'll arrive at FCO at terminal 3 at 20h30, and I'll depart from FCO terminal 1 at 22h00. I have been told by Etihad that they will handle checked luggage through. What is the walking time between these terminals and are there security checks required?

Comment: Still trying to understand if a Schengen or any type of transit visa required, See many responses which refer to USA departures and arrivals but what of a transfer from London to Abu Dhabi with a South African passport. If on a single Etihad ticket with luggage checked through all the way to Johannesburg, do the passengers require visas when moving from Terminal 3 to 1 in Rome?

Comment: Regarding your visa question, see [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30569/32134)

Comment: Thanks question answered in the referred question:  Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area? – mts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area) Note that OP has commented that the link @mts provided answers the question.

Comment: I asked the airline the questions as well and they eventually answered: Note that no need for transit visa at FCO  airport as long as you have connecting flight and 90minutes is ok to connect to another flight.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, and with your luggage checked through as mine was, the 1.5 hour time should be sufficient. Walking from 3 to 1 is a bit circuitous and there are security checks, but it is well signed. Our connection was much tighter than yours, 50 minutes, and we made it with only a slight bottleneck in the security line. Our arrival was mid-morning, which can be busier than when you'll land at FCO. I found the [terminal maps](http://www.adr.it/en/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en-/pax-fco-airport-map) helpful to navigate from [Terminal 3 arrivals](http://www.adr.it/documents/17615/3457317/2017.05.31+T3_arrivi.pdf/87eb3cb5-55d5-4529-ae1a-3d9c023b0567) to the [departures in Terminal 1](http://www.adr.it/documents/17615/3457317/2017.05.30+T1+PARTENZE.pdf/b2a1cfcf-b4bd-4e11-879e-9cb3f5622361). FCO also has a [live flight tracking tool](http://www.adr.it/en/web/aeroporti-di-roma-en-/pax-fco-fiumicino) which you can use to double check your arrival and departure gates and times.